# How to generate PLK for Visual Studio extension nowdays?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am planning to create new extension and want to support old Visual Studio versions (2005+).

Earlier I was able to generate PLK using https://vsipprogram.com/external/key that was hidden one day but still was available via this direct link.

Today this link is being redirected to new place and finally I get error 404, so not found.

Is there any way to get PLK today?

I wrote vsipinfo@microsoft.com as the page suggested, but they never replied me in the past. I can't believe I am the only developer who still wants to support old VS versions.

*It's not a duplicate of [Obtain a PLK for a 2005/2008 VSPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042402/obtain-a-plk-for-a-2005-2008-vspackage) because that answer doesn't work anymore.*

Comment: For new extensions even supporting VS 2010 is very rare nowdays. VS 2015+ or just VS 2017 is much more common.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain a PLK for a 2005/2008 VSPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042402/obtain-a-plk-for-a-2005-2008-vspackage)

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT unfortunately the way mentioned there does not work now.

Answer (score 0):

> How to generate PLK for Visual Studio extension nowdays?

You can try following method:

> - Enroll the VSIP Program (https://vsipprogram.com). The Basic Level is    free. It takes a couple of days to get approval from Microsoft.
> - Click the "Support" link at the bottom of the main page to go to the    FAQ section.
> - There is a "How do I get a PLK/SLK for Visual Studio?" FAQ entry that    points you to the PLK/SLK generator tool.

Certificate: [Obtain a PLK for a 2005/2008 VSPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042402/obtain-a-plk-for-a-2005-2008-vspackage).